# How to make my borders reach all the way to the edge?

Tags: html, asp.net, css

Okay, so I have a website that uses master pages and a CSS stylesheet. I'm having trouble making my table borders reach all the way to the edge. I have a feeling this one is going to take some to troubleshoot, but awesome if not. The website I'm trying to do it with is [here](http://www.traveljoans.com) I've got a border on the main table in the master page and I want to make the border underneath the banner menu to extend all the way to the edge. When I take out the border spacing element for my mainTable style rule, it makes the line extend all the way out, but of course everything is mashed up together. Here is the applicable code:

```
<table class="mainTable">
    <tr>
        <td class="masterBannerTop" colspan="6" >
            <a href="Default.aspx"><img style="border: none; display: block; margin: 0 auto;" alt="Travel Joan's Blog Banner" src="Website%20Photos/HeadBanner.jpg" /></a>
        </td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>

    <td class="masterBannerNav"><a href="Default.aspx">HOME</a></td>
    <td class="masterBannerNav"><a href="About.aspx">ABOUT ME</a></td>
    <td>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" Font-Size="16pt">
        <LevelMenuItemStyles>
            <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="masterBannerMenu" />
        </LevelMenuItemStyles>
        <LevelSubMenuStyles>
            <asp:SubMenuStyle CssClass="subMenuStyle" />
        </LevelSubMenuStyles>
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="WHERE I'VE BEEN" NavigateUrl="~/whereivebeen.aspx">
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="UNESCO Sites" NavigateUrl="~/unesco.aspx" />
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Places" NavigateUrl="~/BlogPosts.aspx" />
                </asp:MenuItem>
            </Items>
        </asp:Menu>
    </td>
    <td class="masterBannerMenu">
        <asp:Menu ID="Menu2" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <LevelSubMenuStyles>
            <asp:SubMenuStyle CssClass="masterBannerMenu" />
        </LevelSubMenuStyles>
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="PHOTOGRAPHY" NavigateUrl="~/photos.aspx">
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Street Photos" NavigateUrl="~/StreetPhotos.aspx" />
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="People Photos" NavigateUrl="~/PeoplePhotos.aspx" />
                </asp:MenuItem>
            </Items>
        </asp:Menu>
    </td>
    <td class="masterBannerNav"><a href="Links.aspx">LINKS</a></td>
    <td class="masterBannerNav"><a href="Contact.aspx">CONTACT ME</a></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6">
             </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;">
             </td>
    </tr>
```

and here's the CSS of all the elements referred to in this code:

```
.mainTable
{
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-spacing:30px;
}
.masterBannerTop a
{
    background-color: transparent;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border:none;
}
.masterBannerNav a
{
    font-family:"Century Gothic";
    font-size: 16pt;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;  
    color: Black;
    text-decoration: none;   
    white-space: nowrap;

}
.masterBannerMenu a
{
    font-family:"Century Gothic";
    font-size: 16pt;
    width: auto;
    text-align: left;  
    color: Black;
    text-decoration: none;   

}
```

I've tried making sure there is no padding in .mainTable. What else?

Comment: It's not really clear what you want the borders to do. `extend all the way to the edge`—but what edge? It's a little vague. I'm sure this is easy to do, but I agree that the first thing to do is remove the border-spacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you realise what `<table>` is meant to contain? Table layout is for tabular data. You don't write mails in Excel.

[This](http://webdesign.about.com/od/layout/a/aa111102a.htm)article might help you to take the right decision.

---

As you set the `border-spacing:30px;`to the `<table>`, you can't make it happen. With `<div>`it would be quite easy.

You can rebuild your layout that way: http://jsfiddle.net/Qtmkw/4/, so you have two `<table>` instead of one, this works :)

Comment: As much as I would like to not use tables, I certainly don't want to take the time to redo the entire site. Tables are hard to maintain and work with, as the article says, and I will use CSS next time, but I most certainly do not want to start over.

Comment: Ok @Joseph, I've just updated my solution with a jsfiddle, hope it helps :)

Comment: Okay, it's going to take me some time to wrap my head around this. So I'll have nested tables. What is that going to do with the rest of my content that's below it? The code above is for my master page, so I'm not sure how adding another table is going to work, but I'll give it a shot and let you know.

Comment: If you close "newMainTable" just after the border and then start new "mainTable", then the rest of the page should just stay the same (don't forget to add the border manually as I've removed it from mainTable class).

Comment: I'll give starting a new table a shot, though I don't believe that's what you have in your jsfiddle. I really appreciate your help with this though! I want to be done with this website! (I'm new)

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help, cause the last time I worked with table layouts was quite a long time ago. Hope you will finish soon this project and carry on with something more challenging!

Comment: I'm closer.... So I essentially have 3 tables, one main table and then two nested tables, one for my banner and navigation menu, and one for my content below it?

Comment: can you take another look at the page? I'm trying to get the vertical border separating the slideshow and about me section to go all the way to the top.